# Function pointer to objc class member method, for use in C++?

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, function-pointers

I have a C++ class which I use for networking (via boost::asio), which requires the use of callback functions in order to do anything useful.
I also have a mixed Objective-C++ project which makes use of this class.
Using objc class singletons, each of my subclassed `UIViewController` classes are able to bind to standard C/C++ methods defined within the class implementation file, of which, in turn, call their respective class member methods via the singleton instance:

```
@interface MyViewControllerClass ()
+ (instancetype)Instance;
@end

MyViewControllerClass *_MyViewControllerClass_Instance;

void cppCallback() {
    // This method gets called from the C++ class
    [[MyViewControllerClass Instance] objcCallback];
}

@implementation MyViewControllerClass

+ (instancetype)Instance {
    return _MyViewControllerClass_Instance;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    _MyViewControllerClass_Instance = self;
    // Pass &cppCallback to the C++ class here, so it can be called later
}

- (void)objcCallback {
    ;// Do something here
}
@end
```

As ugly as it looks, this has worked just fine in the past. But now I've hit a new wall...
I need to utilize the C++ networking class from within a `UICollectionViewCell` subclass, which there will be many instances of... which means the use of a singleton won't work.

So how can I pass a pointer to an objc class method as a C++ parameter?
Is my only option to write a full Objective-C wrapper class for my C++ networking class?

Comment: The callback takes no user, info or similar argument? Usually callbacks takes this to exactly solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Function pointer" is not possible here, because you can't use a function pointer to call an instance method (unless you pass around the instance with the function pointer).

You can create a callable object, however.

```
struct Callback {
    MyViewControllerClass *instance;
    void operator()() {
        [instance objcCallback];
    }
};
```

You could also use a C++ lambda, which is vaguely equivalent.

Comment: I like this idea. I'll have to put it to the test, thanks!

Comment: I've fashioned up a templated version of my network class which uses a very like-minded callback struct, but also does a `conformsToProtocol:` check. Thanks again!